# Windows powershell command to look up tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, tagging

I am trying to work out how to do {something} based off a tag existing on an EC2 instance or not (using powershell as part of bootstrap).. does anyone know the best way to do it ? [if tag={this}, then {this}]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2Tag.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [instance metadata query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) to access instance ID and AWS API/CLI call to get instance tags from the [DescribeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) API:

```
$curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
i-05d7b1954xxxxxxxxx <- my instance ID

aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-05d7b1954xxxxxxxxx
{...} <- grab tags from here.
```

You instance would need a role allowing it to call DescribeInstances API.